# SQL to find Confluence databaser version

Tags: version, confluence

I like to know for a specific Confluence database schema the Confluence release version. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from CONFVERSION;
```

You'll see the 'confversionid' and 'buildnumber' there:

```
confversionid | buildnumber |      installdate       | versiontag | creationdate | lastmoddate 
---------------+-------------+------------------------+------------+--------------+-------------
      34537473 |        6223 | 2019-03-14 18:05:59.85 |            |              | 
(1 row)
```